# php: skip '$this' in object class

Tags: php, oop

Is it any way to skip $this in onject?
Having this class:

```
Class klas
{
  private $var1;
  private $var2;

  public function makeIt()
  {
    echo $this->var1;

  }

}
```

is it way to do this in something like this way:

```
Class klas
{
  private $var1;
  private $var2;

  public function makeIt()
  {
    echo $var1;

  }

}
```

Maybe is somewhere some kind of magic method or domething to do this?

Comment: actually $this does the magic for you since it refers to the current object and using it you can access member data.

Comment: No. There's no easier way. `$classInstance->property` is how you access regular non-static  values in a class. `$this` just refers to the current instance of the class.

Comment: It might be better if you give an overview of what you are trying achieve.  It seems you might need to use static methods but need clarification on the context.

Comment: Not really, and if it were, it wouldn't be advisable, I don't know what are your reasons, if you are just new to php's OOP you will get used to it xD. Give us some explanation about why you are trying to do that and maybe we can point something else out

Comment: I was wondering about that just for time-save reason. If i had lot of code in some method, and have many properties, why dont use just `$val` instead of `$this->val`. But if there is no way to do this, so.. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You could, at the start of the function, assign `$r = &$this` and from there on, use `$r->val`. Saves a little time typing out stuff. I chose `r` because it's right under the `4` key, `e` works just as well (or, really, any key you want).

Comment: No. `$this->foo` tells PHP to look for a class attribute name `foo`, instead of a function-local variable that happens to have the same name.

Comment: No, that's **not** a great idea. sparing those 3 characters just doesn't worth it. **Readability comes first** - "Always write code as if the person who will be maintaining it is a psychotic serial killer who knows where you live". + http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

Comment: @unbreak Sure is if you want to make sure that your code is way **harder to read and understand for all future developers**. Make sure to use variables such as `$var7732` and `$var882` while you're at it, just to make debugging harder.

Comment: It's better to stick with $this. At this end it's only few charactersmand if you are using some good IDE you will have good autocompletion. If you start using tricks like $t = &$this it will
use a little bit more memory and computation time and confuse other developers. Plus with some code autocompletion in Neatbeans for example I'm not sure if it will be able to solve what it's $r

Believe me, this thing won't speed up your development, at the end it will only slow down at add some extra complexity

Comment: @scenia - not a particularly good idea if other people are looking(or will ever need to look) at the code.... saving few keystrokes for one person will add extra thinking work to everyone elses

Comment: Well, it's not a good idea to do it. It is however a good idea to do it this way if you absolutely want to do it in some way, simply because it's probably the only way to do it. I should have pointed it out in the first comment... Will expand this as an answer and elaborate a little.

Comment: @scenia: helping people do stupid things is not a good idea either (meaning: please, don't post an answer...). teach good practices.

Comment: I can answer the question truthfully and completely and still teach good practices. :)

Comment: You can use magic setters and getters if you don't have to have the actual properties listed: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you should have read manual instead.

Comment: @AzizSaleh: that's not relevant (if you don't believe me, try to implement what he asked for).

Comment: This has nothing to do with reading the manual, it's a very legitimate question, especially seeing as the result he's trying to achieve is the way this is done in several other languages. Clearly this question is on topic.

Comment: I cannot believe this question was closed as off-topic. Get a grip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need to *modify* the values, only use them, you can use `extract` in combination with `get_object_vars` to create local **copies**.

This will define any properties within the current symbol table, letting you refer to them as local variables. Note that any changes to them will not affect the corresponding object properties, as these are NOT references, but new copies of the variables.

```
<?php
Class klas
{
  public $foo = 'world';
  private $bar = 'my code';

  public function makeIt()
  {
      extract(get_object_vars($this));
      print 'Hello '.$foo.', velkommen to '.$bar;
      $foo = 'Dave';
  }

}

$inst = new klas();
$inst->makeIt();

print 'Hello '.$inst->foo; // not "Hello Dave"
```

Try it: http://codepad.viper-7.com/eKr1v7

You can also cast the object as an array instead of using `get_object_vars`:

```
$vars = (array)$this;
extract($vars);
```

The documentation of `extract` mentions a `EXTR_REFS` flag, which should extract references into the local symbol table. When you cast the object as an array, the resulting array is said to be references (in comments in PHP docs), but, I was not able to reproduce this on [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NmE056), even though the version is comparable to that referenced in the claim. You can give it a shot on your installation, your mileage may vary.

**Documentation**

- `extract` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php
- `get_object_vars` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Answer (score 2):

Without pointlessly addling boiler-plate code to the local scope...

No, it's not possible, PHP doesn't support such a mechanism.

More importantly, it's totally pointless and bad practice, as many good reputation users already mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I disagree with this answer from a technical perspective -- `extract` and `get_object_vars` are supported mechanisms, and possible.

Comment: @Chris: I think the question is: **what** is possible. scenia also said in his answer "yes, it is possible", though he doesn't even remotely do what the question asks for. And yours doesn't allow modification (I LOL'd here). I interpreted the question the following way: achieve it without fiddling in the current scope (magic methods, configuation... you get the point). really, I don't see the point of adding boiler-plate code in **every** method. That's just stupid. I think there's nothing wrong with my answer, though I amended the wording to make it more clear.

Comment: While we probably all agree that it's bad practice, he asked if there was a way to shorten `$this->attribute`, presumably because he wants to save time typing it out. Both my answer and Chris' present a way to do this. The question does not specify how exactly it should be achieved or whether or not only good practice shall be posted. There's nothing wrong with either of those answers, but yours is just plain wrong. stating it's bad practice has been done in the comments, where it belongs.

Comment: @scenia: "he asked if there was a way to shorten" - he didn't say a word about shorting. he said: "skip $this".

Comment: And both answers present a way to achieve the same result without typing out `$this`, in other words, a way to 'skip' it. Read the question, he even specifically asked for a magic method or something.

Comment: Well, we agree to disagree.

Comment: @Chris: extract is wrong, because it will create a copy of the variables. So it's not "shortening", but instead creating a slightly different variable. [Proof](http://3v4l.org/vljgh). So no, this *is* the correct answer, as it talks about pointless boilerplate, and indicates that it's bad practice in the first place.

Comment: In what point do we disagree? Does the question not ask for "some kind of magic method or [s]omething"? Does either my or Chris' answer not give a way to "skip `$this`"? Do those not imply that "there is no way" is a false statement? Does a comment about how OP's goal is bad practice not belong in the comments rather than an answer? Is it not wrong to downvote a correct and working answer because you think what's being asked in the question should not be done? Ignoring even the fact the answer does not only point out that it's wrong, but also explain why (**in addition** to answering it)?

Comment: @scenia look at the codepad I put in my prior comment. It shows *literally* how Chris's answer doesn't work.

Comment: @ircmaxell woah, woah, woah. It does too work. I am pretty explicit in my answer that these are not references, but copies. I guess I could word it even more explicitly, but the code does exactly what I say it does. The debate about whether you'd ever want to do this is open, I suppose (I would not), but as I mentioned, you can find the technique I am using discussed in upvoted comments right in the PHP docs.

Comment: @Chris: yes, which is why I didn't downvote your answer. But to say that it's possible, while having those limitations is not great either. Really, I think this answer is the only correct one. The others require both boilerplate and enough limitations and restrictions that it's not really the same problem. Which is why I'm defending this answer, because it's the only **general** answer in this question (the others assume a specific sub-question).

Comment: @ircmaxell also, as my demo code and comment referenced in the later section, there is implied behavior that would give you references that I could not reproduce in my own tests. I just don't think anyone here is telling me anything I didn't already know, and mention, in my answer.

Comment: @ircmaxell Yeah, I figured Karoly revenge dv'd me, which is silliness.

Comment: @scenia: "Is it not wrong to downvote a correct and working answer because you think what's being asked in the question should not be done?" - just a small correction: neither what was being asked, neither the solution. **I** think it's the right thing(tm) to do.. and I'm absolutely sure about one thing: this is not the right place to discuss it. feel free to post a question about this on meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to save a few characters if you have to type it a lot. At the start of the function, assign

```
$r = $this;
```

and from there on, use `$r->val`. This saves a little time typing out stuff. I chose `r` because it's right under the `4` key, `e` works just as well (or, really, any key you want).

**However**, note that this is a **bad idea** in general, mainly for 2 reasons.

1. You're assigning a new variable. Since it's only a reference, this means a tiny bit of additional memory used up, but it also slightly **increases computation time** because `PHP` handles `$this` more efficiently than assigned variables.
2. Your code becomes **less readable**. While the "pure" version you suggested in the question is probably more or less readable depending on your background (several languages do it that way), the native `PHP` way is very clear, especially because nearly every editor will highlight `$this`. It removes all possibility for confusion as it shows, without room for interpretation, that the current object is the one whose attributes or methods you're accessing. It also shows very clearly that you're nor handling some local variable *(local to the function call, or more specifically, to this instance of the function call)*, but rather an attribute of the object the method is called on.

So, what it comes down to, is that **yes, it is possible** in a tricky way, but **you shouldn't do it**.

Comment: You're actually not assigning a new variable as all objects are references by default.

Comment: Doesn't it store the reference pointer though? I honestly don't know how the interpreter works internally, does it just compile all references to an object the same way, no matter what they're named?

Comment: You'd essentially only use a tiny memory stamp because of the reference (the variable named `$r` points to the variable in this part of the memory (the same as `$this`)). Otherwise they're [a reference to the same variable](http://codepad.org/09aYlkME).

Comment: Yep - that seems much better :)